# Send HTTPS request (SSL) ON esp32 without using certificate or fingerprint

Tags: c, ssl, https, arduino, esp32

I am new to Ardunio and i am facing an issue while sending a post api request to my server(with SSL) from ESP32. The API is working well with web portal and mobile app but not with my micro controller. I can understand the embedded system are different than web and mobile.

I don't want to hard code certificate or fingerprint in ardunio sketch.

Error: I get a connection refused error when I am using to get/post data from Ardino.
Below is the code snippet:

```
BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure client;
client.setInsecure();
HTTPClient https;
String apiPath = “”;
if (https.begin(client, baseURL , 443, apiPath)) { ... }
```

PS: I did a quick test using ESP8266 using library  and request worked but not working for ESP32.

Any pointers would be helpful here.

Comment: You don't need the certificate of your site. If your SSL server has a certificate which ends up being signed by a proper certificate authority (e.g. letsencrypt), you only need its root certificate. The underlying ESP-IDF framework has a [root certificate bundle](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_crt_bundle.html) used by the [HTTP client](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_client.html) which would work. I'm not sure that your Arduino HTTPS client uses the bundle, though.

Answer (score 0):

hope you get an answer for that but it will not work without a certificate as this is the basic HTTPS rules, consider adding an http request to refresh the hard coded certificate will is the only.
also check the latest IDF version 3.0.0 and above seems to solve it.

Comment: *it will not work without a certificate as this is the basic HTTPS rules*  [The TLS protocol does support anonymous ciphers that do not require certificates](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4).  The problem is that most off-the-shelf implementations do not support anonymous cipher suites, so you'd have to do something like compile OpenSSL from source to use anonymous ciphers.  Note there's also a `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` that not only doesn't do authentication, it doesn't use encryption or do any message hashing either.